# Laravel saving data to two locations

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a larvel project where the user can create appointments. In addition I've created another model called clients so when a user creates an appointment the users "client" data is saved.

In my appointments controller I have the following: -

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);

        //create appointment
        $apt = new Appointment;
        $apt->name = $request->input('name');
        $apt->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $apt->save();

        //create client
        $client = new Client;
        $client->first_name = $request->input('name');
        $client->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $client->save();

        return redirect('/appointments')->with('success', 'Appointment created');
    }
```

When saving the data it works and stores the data in the clients table however I know this isn't the cleanest way of saving the data, but what is the "laravel" way of doing this?

Comment: Are the appointments and clients related in any way?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: If your business logic is to create a new client every time you create a new appointment, you could put that in a model event.

Comment: I think you should Use one to one relationship

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/appdividend.com/amp/2017/10/12/laravel-one-to-one-eloquent-relationships/

Comment: If you code is working and you're looking for a "cleaner" approach, then this isn't really a question for Stackoverflow, but rather CodeReview: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. It's totally fine keeping it that way.

I prefer to say Model::create() to create models in one statement.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
    ]);

    Appointment::create([
        'name' => request('name'),
        'user_id' => auth()->id()
    ]);

    Client::create([
        'first_name' => request('name'),
        'user_id' => auth()->id,
    ]);

    return redirect('/appointments')->with('success', 'Appointment created');
}
```

You can also use [tap()](https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/tap-tap-tap-1fc6fc1f93a6) function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
    ]);

    tap(Appointment::create(['name' => request('name'), 'user_id' => auth()->id()]), function ($newAppoinment) {
        Client::create([
            'first_name' => $newAppoinment->name,
            'user_id' => auth()->id,
        ]);

    });

    return redirect('/appointments')->with('success', 'Appointment created');
}
```

Or the best approach could be using [model events](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#events):

```
class Appointment extends Model
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function ($appointment) {
            Client::create([
                'user_id' => $appoinment->user_id,
                'first_name' => $appoinment->name, 
            ])
        });
    }
}
```